# What happens if you clone Harvest Hand and sacrifice the clone?

Tags: magic-the-gathering, mtg-double-faced-cards

[Harvest Hand](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Harvest%20Hand) reads
"When Harvest Hand dies, return it to the battlefield transformed under your control."

If a creature copying Harvest Hand died, it wouldn't be able to transform when the dies trigger resolves because it has no back side. Would it re-enter the battlefield on its front side or not at all?

Answer (score 7):

**If a creature copying Harvest Hand dies, it stays in the graveyard.**

[Rule 702.10a](https://mtg.fandom.com/wiki/Double-faced_card) says

> If a spell or ability puts a transforming double-faced card onto the battlefield “transformed,” it enters the battlefield with its back face up. **If a player is instructed to put a card that isn’t a transforming double-faced card onto the battlefield transformed, that card stays in its current zone.**

The ability resolves while the card that was copying the Harvest Hand is in the graveyard, so the card stays in the graveyard.

Comment: Unless the card copying Harvest Hand is a transforming DFC, in which case it will return to the battlefield transformed into whatever its backside is.